# Parsing a date returned as JSON in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, json

Hi I was receiving responses from an API as JSON and loading it into my application. Everything imports fine except for a date that that a specific item was published on. The date is returned as a number which I never worked with before:

```
'date_created' : 1279643054
```

I tried using a normal DateTime.Parse() with no luck. Does anyone know how to parse this, or if anything what the name of this format is so I can do further research? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [UNIX Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Use this code to convert the timestamp to a `DateTime` object:

```
static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(long timestamp)
{
    return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(timestamp);
}
```

Comment: You may also want to additionally call `.ToLocalTime()`.